# The Css for my menu isn't showing on my Html page

Tags: php, html, css

I was working on the homepage of my website and all of a sudden the menu stopped working. The Html page is connected with a menu file and that menu file is connected with the Css. I don't remember editing anything that has to do with the menu. Can someone please help?

This is how it looks now:
[The Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztJEA.png)

The Menu file:

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li> <img src="images\cbr-logo.png" width=100> </li>
  <li><a href="index.php"> <span>Home</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="theorie.php"><span>Theorie</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="examen.php"><span>Examen</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="directie.php"><span>Directie</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="login.php"><span>Uitloggen</span></a></li>
</ul>
<br>
<br>
<hr>
```

The Html file:

```
<?php 
    require 'core/init.php';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css?V=01">
    <title>CBR Theorie examen </title>  
  </head>

  <body>    
    <div id="container">
      <?php
          echo '<div>';
          include 'includes/menu.php';
          echo '</div>';

      ?>

    <div id="containercontainer">

        <div id="titel">
            <h1 class="titel">Home</h1>
        </div>
<!-- de slideshow ======================================================== -->      
      <div id="slideshow">
            <div class="fling-minislide">
                <img src="images\slideshow1.jpg" alt="Slideshow 3" />
                <img src="images\slideshow2.jpg" alt="Slideshow 2" />
                <img src="images\slideshow3.jpg" alt="Slideshow 1" />
            </div>
      </div>

<!-- Nieuws  ================================================================================== -->       
        <div id="nieuws">
            <h1 style="width: 300px;" class="titel">Digitaal Examen</h1><br>
            <img class="nieuws" src="images/computer.jpg" alt="nieuws plaatje" />
            <p class="nieuws">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis in erat laoreet sem <br>
            scelerisque pulvinar. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et <br>
            malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Suspendisse interdum placerat leo, ac iaculis <br>
            posuere eu. In non pulvinar ipsum. Vestibulum pretium sem nec enim pharetra, ac <br>
            sapien tempor. Praesent odio ipsum, vehicula at viverra ut, consectetur et sapien.<br>
            vel congue dolor, sit amet pulvinar felis. Pellentesque et turpis viverra, <br>
            tempus metus. Nunc porta sapien eget elit maximus dictum sed sed dolor. <br>
            velit et nibh dapibus, ac vulputate orci bibendum. Donec blandit faucibus <br>
            malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Suspendisse interdum placerat leo, ac iaculis <br>
            posuere eu. In non pulvinar ipsum. Vestibulum pretium sem nec enim pharetra, ac <br>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis in erat laoreet sem <br>
            scelerisque pulvinar. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et <br>   
            </p>
        </div>

<!-- Veel gestelde vragen ======================================================================= -->       
        <div id="vragen">
            <p class="A">Veel gestelde vragen</p>
            <div id="pointer">          
            </div>
            <p class="vragentop"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit?</p>
            <p class="vragentext1">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis in erat laoreet sem <br>
            scelerisque pulvinar. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et <br>
            malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Suspendisse interdum placerat leo, ac iaculis <br>
            posuere eu. In non pulvinar ipsum. Vestibulum pretium sem nec enim pharetra, ac <br>
            sapien tempor. Praesent odio ipsum, vehicula at viverra ut, consectetur et sapien.<br>
            vel congue dolor, sit amet pulvinar felis. Pellentesque et turpis viverra, <br>
            </p>
        </div>

     </div> 

    </div>
  </body>


<body>


    <!-- notification message -->
    <?php if (isset($_SESSION['success'])) : ?>
      <div class="error success" >
        <h3>
          <?php 
            echo $_SESSION['success']; 
            unset($_SESSION['success']);
          ?>
        </h3>
      </div>
    <?php endif ?>

    <!-- logged in user information -->
    <?php  if (isset($_SESSION['naam'])) : ?>
        <p>Welkom <strong><?php echo $_SESSION['naam']; ?></strong></p>
    <?php endif ?>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

The Css file:

```
@charset "utf-8";

body {
  font: 0.9em Tahoma, Verdana, Arial;
  line-height:172%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 0px;
}

.center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

#containercontainer {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  padding: 30px;

}


/* bovenste kopje ========================================*/
h1.titel {
  color: black;
  font: Gill Sans, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: -2px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}


#titel {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border-bottom: solid black 1px;
  width: 5.5%;
  left: 45%;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}




/* De Slideshow ========================================*/


.fling-minislide {
    width:100%; 
    height:100%; 
    padding-bottom: 0%; 
    overflow:hidden; 
    position:relative; 
    }

.fling-minislide img{ 
    position:absolute; 
    animation:fling-minislide 15s infinite; 
    opacity: 0;  
    size: 100% 100%;
    }

@keyframes fling-minislide {33%{opacity:1;} 60%{opacity:0;}} 
    .fling-minislide img:nth-child(3){animation-delay:0s;}
    .fling-minislide img:nth-child(2){animation-delay:5s;}
    .fling-minislide img:nth-child(1){animation-delay:10s;}

#slideshow {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  float: center;
  border: solid black 2px;
  width: 55%;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  left: 21%;
}

/* Het nieuws blokje ========================================*/

img.nieuws {
  margin-top: -20px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  border: solid black 2px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

p.nieuws {
  float: right;
  margin-top: -10px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 20px;

}

#nieuws {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  width: 78%;
  height: 50px;
  left: 10%;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

/* Het vragen blokje ========================================*/


#vragen {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  width: 80%;
  padding-left: 0px;
  height: 1000px;
  left: 10%;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  top: 300px;
  border: solid black 1px;
}


p.A{
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 22px;
  width: 250px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

    #pointer {
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      position: relative;
      background: black;
      margin-left: 30px;
    }
    #pointer:after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      border-left: 10px solid white;
      border-top: 10px solid transparent;
      border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    }
    #pointer:before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      right: -10px;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      border-left: 10px solid black;
      border-top: 10px solid transparent;
      border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    }

p.vragentop {
    margin-left: 80px;
    margin-top: -25px;
    text-decoration: underline;
    width: 400px;

}

p.vragentext1 {
  margin-left: 80px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;


  /*/////////////////////////////////////////////////*/



#cbrlogo {
    background: #fff;
    width: 50px;
}

#container {
  width: relative;
  padding: relative;
  background: #fff;
  min-height: 500px;
}

#containercontainer2 {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  padding: 30px;
}

.afbeelding_container {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.afbeelding_container .tekst_container {
  position: relative;
  top: 25px;
  left: 50px;
  color: #00f;
  font-size: 36px;

}

.schoon {
  clear: both;
}


#overzicht {
  margin-left: 25px;
}

.links {
  float: left;
  width: 320px;
}

#rechts {
  float: right;
}

#onder {
  clear: both;
}

.breder {
  width: 4000px;
}

ul {
  padding-left: 35px;
  padding-right: 35px;
  list-style: none;
  background: 00f;
}

hr {
  margin: 0px 0;
  height: 1px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-top: 10px solid #00f;
  background-color: #fff;
}

a:link {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:active {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu {
    display: block;
    margin: 0px;
    padding:0px;
    position: absolute; 
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #3695F6;
}


ul.menu {
    list-style-type: none;
}

img.menu {
    height: 40px;
    width: 30%;
    position:relative;
    margin: 10px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.menu li {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    width: 200px;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu li a {
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}

.menu li a span{
  display: block;
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255,);
  font-size: 18px;
}

.menu li:hover span{
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

th {
  padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px;
}

td {
  padding: 0 30px 0 30px;
}

td.muteren {
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
}


tbody:before {
    line-height:1em;
    display:block;
}

thead {
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: We need a bit more information. What exactly does _"stopped working"_ mean? It just looks like a list of links? How are they not working?

Comment: there is a Parsing Errors in your CSS RBRACE is missing and # is missing for color 00f

Comment: I added a picture of the website menu and fixed the #00f color but nothing changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget to put closing bracket in **p.vragentext1**

**Replace your code**

```html
p.vragentext1 {
  margin-left: 80px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
```

**With**

```html
p.vragentext1 {
  margin-left: 80px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}
```